# Xamarin Forms Droid - No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'XXXXXXXX'

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set up the envirenment needed to start developing my first Xamarin forms application, but whenever i try to build the project i get this error: 
[image]

which obviously a problem with the Android project. i tried to build with different versions of Android and different versions of Dlls. 
here is my pachages file:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <packages>   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="24.2.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package id="Xamarin.Forms"
> version="1.5.1.6471" targetFramework="monoandroid70" /> </packages>
```

I have updated the dlls of Android support to the latest version but that didn't help. 
Also I downloaded different versions of Android SDKs and tried to compile the project with, but that has not solve the problem.
I would love to know what versions of either dlls or android should i use.. and what the compilation process setting should be targeting of the different Android verions?
Thanks

Comment: One thing to be careful of is to ensure you only allow `Xamarin.Forms` to update the support libraries as it has a hard dependency on them. I would advise that you remove all these packages and update only `Xamarin.Forms` to the latest stable. You should then ensure your `TargetFramework` is set to >= the latest API version such as 23/24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be that you cancelled the build, because it took very long and seemed hanging? If yes, you may have caused a bad state. You have to delete some folders in order to get the build running again.

See: http://smstuebe.de/2016/10/29/fix-android-app-compat/

Comment: That is exactly what my problem was... Thank you man.. 
This issue is confusing because the build process take like forever to complete with no logging information in the output bar. I think VS should've said anything during this downloading process, because anyone would think that VS is hanged and would kill the process just as i did.. Thank you again.